# printing a number table of square

Tags: python, numbers

```
n: 8
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
 8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47
48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55
56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63
```

How to print a number table like this in python with n that can be any number?
I am using a very stupid way to print it but the result is not the one expected:

```
n = int(input('n: '))
if n == 4:
    print(' 0 1 2 3\n4 5 6 7\n8 9 10 11\n12 13 14 15')
if n == 5:
    print(' 0 1 2 3 4\n5 6 7 8 9\n10 11 12 13 14\n15 16 17 18 19\n20 21 22 23 24')
if n == 6:
    print(' 0 1 2 3 4 5\n6 7 8 9 10 11\n12 13 14 15 16 17\n18 19 20 21 22 23\n24 25 26 27 28 29\n30 31 32 33 34 35')
if n == 7:
    print(' 0 1 2 3 4 5 6\n7 8 9 10 11 12 13\n14 15 16 17 18 19 20\n21 22 23 24 25 26 27\n28 29 30 31 32 33 34\n35 36 37 38 39 40 41\n42 43 44 45 46 47 48')
if n == 8:
    print(' 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7\n8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15\n16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23\n24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31\n32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39\n40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47\n48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55\n56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63')
if n == 9:
    print(' 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8\n9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17\n18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26\n27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35\n36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44\n45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53\n54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62\n63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71\n72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80')
if n == 10:
    print(' 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9\n10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19\n20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29\n30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39\n40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49\n50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59\n60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69\n70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79\n80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89\n90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99')
```

here is the result:

```
n: 8
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47
48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55
56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63
```

Comment: It's just two nested `for` loops.  What have you tried?

Comment: @TimRoberts i think that's what is in the question is what they've tried!

Comment: I'm afraid, Lzz, the real correct answer here is that you need to read the next page of whatever introduction to python you're reading. This is really something you should learn from guided materials, not from asking here: you're really just asking us to give you an introduction course to python, and that's too broad for a question here.

Comment: As mentioned you can use two nested for loops rather than hardcoding for different n.  As a hint to print out number `j` with a field width of two and a space between each j you can use: `print(f'{j:2d}', end = ' ')`

Answer (score 0):

I won't show you the code directly, here is some tips for you. Do you know `%` operator in python? And how to use it to break lines. As for the format, `zfill` function will help you. You may need to learn `for` or `while` statement to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a range loop and a list comprehension.

In order for the output to look right you need to figure out what the width of the largest value in the square will be. You then need to format each value to fit in that width (right-justified). Something like this:

```
def number_square(n):
    w = len(str(n*n-1))
    for r in range(n):
        print(*[f'{c:>{w}}' for c in range(r*n, r*n+n)])

number_square(8)
```

**Output:**

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
 8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47
48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55
56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63
```